# Why do source maps contain "names"?

Tags: javascript, debugging, source-maps, file-format

[Source maps](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k) contain a field called "names", but isn't this redundant?

"mappings" already maps tokens to locations of tokens in output files to their corresponding locations in source files, and the names are already in the source files.